# Using native query with jpa repsitory

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```
@Repository
public interface SiteRiskRepository extends JpaRepository<SiteRisk, Long> {
@Query(value="SELECT  DATE_TRUNC('day',updated_on)+date_part('hour',updated_on)::int/2 * INTERVAL '2 hour',avg(risk_value) FROM site_risk_tbl WHERE updated_on BETWEEN :fromDate AND :toDate and site_id = :siteId group by 1 order by 1",nativeQuery = true)

    public List<AggttRisk> getSiteRiskTrend(@Param("siteId") String siteId, @Param("fromDate") Date fromDate,
            @Param("toDate") Date toDate);
}

//projection class
public interface AggttRisk {
    String getRiskValue();
    String getUpdatedOn();  
}
```

Giving me error:

> nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set:
>   [:int] [SELECT 
>   DATE_TRUNC('day',updated_on)+date_part('hour',updated_on)::int/2 *
>   INTERVAL '2 hour',avg(risk_value) FROM site_risk_tbl WHERE updated_on
>   BETWEEN :fromDate AND :toDate and site_id = :siteId group by 1 order
>   by 1]]

P.S.: the query works fine while fired on pgadmin.

Comment: probably getting confused with `::int` - is it needed?

Comment: Yes, it is needed.If removed, giving nullPointerException

Comment: does it work in pgadmin?

Comment: yes,it worked there.

Comment: so I would guess that the NPE is something else.  Anyway see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169582/escaping-the-colon-character-in-jpa-queries

Comment: the solution you provided is not working,hence no duplicate.

Comment: Please edit your question with what you have tried from the duplicate and what errors it is producing

Comment: It is giving null pointer exception

Comment: Please edit your question with what you have tried from the duplicate and what errors it is producing

Comment: Okay. i did a workaround and finally cam with the solution. I used List of Object class to gather the objects returned by query and it worked. thanks!

Comment: @Query(value="SELECT  DATE_TRUNC('day',updated_on)+CAST(date_part('hour',updated_on) as Integer)/2 * INTERVAL '2 hour' as updated_on,avg(risk_value) as risk_value FROM site_risk_tbl WHERE updated_on BETWEEN :fromDate AND :toDate and site_id = :siteId group by 1 order by 1",nativeQuery = true)
public List<Object[]> getSiteRiskTrend(@Param("siteId") String siteId, @Param("fromDate") Date fromDate,
   @Param("toDate") Date toDate);

Comment: Please unmark it as duplicate.

Comment: As stated in the duplicate I posted, the colons in `::int` need to be escaped such as `select * from component where data \\:\\:json ->> ?1 = ?2`