# Spring Boot JPA - SQL error on native query double apostrophe

Tags: spring, postgresql, jpa

I have a large query that works perfectly fine in normal postgres, but when I run in a JPA native query I get the following error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ":"
```

The query contains the following line:

```
...
WHERE  year = extract( year FROM CURRENT_DATE - '2 month'::interval)::int 
    and month = extract( month FROM CURRENT_DATE - '2 month'::interval)::int 
...
```

I tried escaping by adding a \ before each apostrophe but the code won't compile:

```
error: illegal escape character
      "    WHERE  year = extract( year FROM CURRENT_DATE - '2 month'\:\:interval)\:\:int and month = extract( month FROM CURRENT_DATE - '2 month'\:\:interval)\:\:int  \n" +
```

Is it not possible to use :: in a native query? Again this works perfectly fine when run normally.

Comment: JPA unconditionally takes a `:` for parameter name indicator. Every colon must be escaped with _two_ backslashes (\\\). You may have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169582/escaping-the-colon-character-in-jpa-queries) SO thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid the headache figuring the necessary escape sequence completely. Postgres uses the double colon (::) as a proprietary CAST operation, but the SQL standard is supported. Also, rather than casting the character string `'2 month'` as an interval you can *declare it as such* by prefixing it. Your clause then becomes:

```
where year =  cast (extract( year  FROM CURRENT_DATE - interval '2 month') as integer)
  and month = cast (extract( month FROM CURRENT_DATE - interval '2 month') as integer)
```

No escape required. And makes it a lot easier to read (i.e. understand).