# Construct a Criteria Api Predicate that overlaps a tsrange column type in Postgresql

Tags: java, spring, criteria-api, criteriaquery

I want to create a Java Criteria Api Predicate that performs the equivalent SQL query in Postgres 15 as follows:

```
SELECT time_range_column FROM public.address_table
WHERE  time_range_column && '[2014-09-23, 2015-09-24]'::tsrange;
```

I declared the `time_range_column` in my entity as follows:

```
@Type(PostgreSQLRangeType.class)
@Column(name = "time_range_column")
private Range\<LocalDateTime\> timeRangeColumn;
```

My solution is as follows, but returns no results:

```
String dateTimeString1 = "2014-09-15 00:00:00";
String dateTimeString2 = "2015-09-15 00:00:00";
String dateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateTimeFormat);
LocalDateTime d1 = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeString1, formatter);
LocalDateTime d2 = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeString2, formatter);

String rangeLiteral = "[" + d1 + "," + d2 + ")";

Predicate dateRangePredicate = criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.literal(rangeLiteral)
.in(root.<LocalDateTime>get("time_range_column")));
```

How to create the predicate that overlaps these dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

`::` or `&&` are not part of the `JPA Criteria API` standard. **You could use a native SQL query.**

---

If you want to use specific features or functions unique to a database system like `PostgreSQL`, it may not be possible to use them directly within the JPA Criteria API.

Some queries, [you can avoid the headache by specifying the escape sequence completely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69773402/2039546), but for this query; There is no way to simultaneously escape special types such as `overlap (&&)`, `double colon (::)`, and `tsrange (cast(string as tsrange))`.

It would be appropriate to create this query using a *native query (@Query)* instead of the Criteria API, or alternatively; if you are using `Hibernate` you can create a `FunctionContributor` for this statement.

Create a *FunctionContributor*, here we give our function a special name and set our pattern:

*(It is a simple function definition approach, it can be made more usable.)*

```java
public class PostgreSQLTsrangeOverlapFunction implements FunctionContributor {

    @Override
    public void contributeFunctions(FunctionContributions functionContributions) {
        functionContributions.getFunctionRegistry().registerPattern(
                "fn_tsrange_overlap",
                "?1 && ?2::tsrange",
                functionContributions
                        .getTypeConfiguration()
                        .getBasicTypeRegistry()
                        .resolve(StandardBasicTypes.BOOLEAN)
        );
    }
}
```

We use this function with the Criteria API:

```java
public static Specification> getSpecification() {
    return (root, query, cb) -> {
        String dateTimeString1 = "2014-09-15 00:00:00";
        String dateTimeString2 = "2015-09-15 00:00:00";
        String dateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateTimeFormat);
        LocalDateTime d1 = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeString1, formatter);
        LocalDateTime d2 = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeString2, formatter);

        Path<Object> field = root.get("time_range_column");
        Expression<String> bound = cb.literal("[" + d1 + "," + d2 + "]");
        Expression<Boolean> function = cb.function(
                "fn_tsrange_overlap",
                Boolean.class,
                field,
                bound);

        return cb.isTrue(function);
    };
}
```

The class must be then registered via [Java ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) mechanism by adding full name of the class with its packages into the file with name `org.hibernate.boot.model.FunctionContributor` into the java module’s `META-INF/services` directory.

You use this specification your query will look like this:

```sql
select ... from table t1 
where t1.time_range_column && '[2014-09-15T00:00,2015-09-15T00:00]'::tsrange
```

*It was prepared with `Spring Boot 3.2.1` and `Hibernate 6.2.7.Final`.*