# How to add time to timestamp in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following fields:

```
field_a TIMESTAMP(0)
field_b TIME
```

Is this possible to add `field_b` to `field_a` using SQL without any special custom functions?

Comment: You would need some function here AFAIK.  If `field_b` had a certain time _unit_, such as hours, then you could use addition with the `interval` syntax.

Comment: So what is your expected result of `'2021-12-06 08:21:45' + '17:42:10'`?

Comment: `'2021-12-06 08:21:45' + '17:42:10' = '2021-12-07 02:03:55'`

Comment: Then you need data type `interval`, not `time` (which is a point in time rather than a duration).

Comment: In fact you are adding an `interval` to the timestamp, not `time`. The expression to do so is `select '2021-12-06 08:21:45'::timestamp + '17:42:10'::interval;`, i.e. `field_a + field_b::interval` will do.

Comment: So your `time` is actually a _duration_. In that case you should be storing it as an `interval`. A `time` value is a "point in time" (e.g. this afternoon at 17"). It's **not** a duration.

Comment: Well this is not working: `field_a + field_b::interval`. I am doing this in Java with nativeQuery:  `SELECT COUNT(V) FROM VISIT V WHERE V.VISIT_DATE <= :newVisitDate AND V.VISIT_DATE + V.VISIT_DURATION::INTERVAL >= :newVisitDateEnd;`  
`ERROR: syntax error at or near ":" 
Resolved [org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet]`

Comment: The reason is that nativeQuery misinterprets your expression. There is no syntax error but `::` needs to be escaped. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169582/escaping-the-colon-character-in-jpa-queries) post to fix it, the second answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is working fine!

Comment: Use `cast(field_b as interval)` in your obfuscation layer.