# Spring BOOT JPA, Custom SQL Query with mysql added row number in Select from INFORMATION SCHEMA

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, information-schema

Hi i have working query in mySQL:
QUERY:

> SELECT TABLE_NAME,(@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num FROM (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t,INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE 'dmind';

[image]

Database name  is dmind.

So what i want to do is Get this Information in Spring Boot JpaRepository
Here is the code i have:
MODEL:

```
@Entity
```

public class DatabaseModel1 {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "num")
private Long ID;



@Column(name = "TABLE_NAME")
private String tableName;

public DatabaseModel1(){

}

public DatabaseModel1(Long ID, String tableName) {
    this.ID = ID;
    this.tableName = tableName;
}

public Long getID() {
    return ID;
}

public void setID(Long ID) {
    this.ID = ID;
}

public String getTableName() {
    return tableName;
}

public void setTableName(String tableName) {
    this.tableName = tableName;
}
```

}

Thats is the REPO

@Repository
public interface DatabaseRepo extends JpaRepository<DatabaseModel1, Long> {

```
@Query(value = "SELECT TABLE_NAME,(@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num FROM (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t,INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE 'dmind'" , nativeQuery = true)
List<DatabaseModel1> finddatabase();
```

}

And The controller:

```
  @GetMapping("/data")
public List<DatabaseModel1> getdabase(){
    return databaseRepo.finddatabase();
}
```

So When i make Request From POSTMAN I get this Result

```
timestamp": "2022-03-14T15:13:06.160+00:00",
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"trace": "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.QueryException: Space is not allowed after parameter prefix ':' [SELECT TABLE_NAME,(@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num FROM (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t,INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE 'dmind']; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: Space is not allowed after parameter prefix ':' [SELECT TABLE_NAME,(@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num FROM (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t,INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE 'dmind']\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:374)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:235)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)\r\n\tat jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy105.finddatabase(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat com.dbcompairbackend.controller.EmployeeController.getdabase(EmployeeController.java:43)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:359)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1735)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)\r\nCaused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: Space is not allowed after parameter prefix ':' [SELECT TABLE_NAME,(@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num FROM (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t,INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE 'dmind']\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getNativeQueryImplementor(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1147)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createNativeQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1043)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createNativeQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1053)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createNativeQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:114)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362)\r\n\tat jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy94.createNativeQuery(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311)\r\n\tat jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy94.createNativeQuery(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.NativeJpaQuery.createJpaQuery(NativeJpaQuery.java:72)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery.doCreateQuery(AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery.java:89)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.createQuery(AbstractJpaQuery.java:227)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:128)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:90)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:155)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:143)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:159)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)\r\n\t... 58 more\r\nCaused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: Space is not allowed after parameter prefix ':' [SELECT TABLE_NAME,(@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num FROM (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t,INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE 'dmind']\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.ParameterParser.parse(ParameterParser.java:175)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.ParamLocationRecognizer.parseLocations(ParamLocationRecognizer.java:56)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.query.internal.NativeQueryInterpreterStandardImpl.getParameterMetadata(NativeQueryInterpreterStandardImpl.java:30)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.lambda$getSQLParameterMetadata$0(QueryPlanCache.java:135)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:330)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getSQLParameterMetadata(QueryPlanCache.java:135)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getNativeQueryImplementor(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1140)\r\n\t... 92 more\r\n",
"message": "org.hibernate.QueryException: Space is not allowed after parameter prefix ':' [SELECT TABLE_NAME,(@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num FROM (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t,INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE 'dmind']; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: Space is not allowed after parameter prefix ':' [SELECT TABLE_NAME,(@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num FROM (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t,INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE 'dmind']",
"path": "/api/v1/data"
```

So if you can help me out how i can do that Please Write any suggestions you have:)

Comment: Colon is a special character for JPA, used in JPQL queries. [Take a look at this question and the solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169582/escaping-the-colon-character-in-jpa-queries).

Comment: TY A LOT WORKED  <3